# PHP's strtotime() doesn't work with April's abbreviation (apr)

Tags: php, date, strtotime

When writing:

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('Mar-29-2016')) . "<br />";
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('Apr-3-2016'));
```

I'd expect to get:

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

But in actuality get:

```
00:00:00
16:16:00
```

Changing to:

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('March 29 2016')) . "<br />";
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('April 3 2016'));
```

Works as expected by outputting:

```
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

What about strtotime() don't I understand?

Comment: How about this `echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('Apr-03-2016'));`?

Comment: Adding the leading 0 works correctly as well.  Why does strtotime() give a timestamp without it?

Comment: You notice that [if you use M-D-Y format](https://eval.in/547545) it works correctly. Just use that format. The PHP time and date functions all tend to revolve around either unix timestamps or American formats for dates, e.g. MM-DD-YYYY - the magic conversion from "any format" to a unix timestamp has its flaws, which are heavily documented on StackOverflow if you search for them.

Comment: Why don't you use `DateTime::createFromFormat` if you want to parse a specific format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime('Apr-03-2016'));
```

The strtotime function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

"Apr-3-2016" is not a valid PHP compound date/time string.  Convert your string to something that `strtotime()` can recognize.  For example, compare the first result below (your string) to some other options:

```
echo date('r', strtotime('Apr-3-2016')) . "\n"; 
echo date('r', strtotime('3-Apr-2016')) . "\n";
echo date('r', strtotime('2016-04-03')) . "\n";
echo date('r', strtotime('4/3/2016'))   . "\n";

Sun, 03 Apr 2016 16:16:00 -0400
Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00 -0400
Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00 -0400
Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:00:00 -0400
```

To convert your "Apr-3-2016" format to "3-Apr-2016", for example:

```
$date = "Apr-3-2016";
list($m, $d, $y) = explode("-", $date);
$newdate = join("-", array($d, $m, $y));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Apr-3-2016` isn't a valid date format. From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
Month abbreviation, day and year    M "-" DD "-" y  "May-09-78", "Apr-17-1790"
```